# Matlab - GUI " Displaying Input and output in GUI"

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am currently working on a Matlab project which deals with GUI. Actually i want to follow the following procedure

1.Take input (numerical) through a GUI (Done).

- Storing them in the input.txt file.
- Use a Matlab Program take input from Input.txt and run the process and finally Storing them in Output.txt (i have written this code and it is working).
- Finally taking this values from Output.txt and displaying them in GUI.

  Following are my doubts :

  1. How do i store the inputs from GUI to Input.txt ?
  2. What code do i have to write in GUI to triger the matlab programe once the input have been stored in a .txt file?
  3. How to take data (numerical values) from Output.txt and display the Output in GUI?

Answer (score 0):

1. *How do I store the inputs from GUI to Input.txt ?*

There are many options, amon which [`dlmwrite`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) and [`fprintf`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?searchHighlight=fprintf).

2. *What code do I have to write in GUI to triger the matlab programe once the input have been stored in a .txt file?*

Simply the name of your script/function, and it will be executed.

3. *How to take data (numerical values) from Output.txt and display the Output in GUI?*

It depends on how your text file is organized, but generally [`dlmread`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html?searchHighlight=dlmread) is perfect for this.

Best,

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this and let you know.